# Collaps function on Date from SQL, failing to give result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use collapse on date, but the query shown below is giving ;ast value of table followed with comma with last value itself.

Same if I apply on `Varchar` value it works fine.

```
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(8000)  

SELECT @Names = COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),CONVERT(DATE,t1.StartDateTime,103)) + ', ', '') 
                + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),CONVERT(DATE,t1.StartDateTime,103)) 
FROM   tabletest t1 
where t1.StartDateTime BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE,@StartDate,103) AND CONVERT(DATE,@Enddate,103)
SELECT @Names
```

I have column values like this

```
+----------
|11-12-2015 |
|12-12-2015 | 
|13-12-2015 |
|14-12-2015 |
|15-12-2015 |
|16-12-2015 |
|___________|
```

I want output as ...

```
(11-12-2015,12-12-2015,13-12-2015,14-12-2015,15-12-2015,16-12-2015)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  SQL Server does not guarantee the values assigned to variables in a `select` statement that has multiple rows.

Comment: provided data and required output

Comment: Use XML PATH to concatenate strings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code have solved my problem

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',' ,'') + Isnull(CAST (CONVERT(DATE,SP.StartDateTime,103) as Varchar),'')
FROM testtable AS SP
SELECT @listStr
GO
```